# Downloading tutorial videos from sites

Tags: video, screencasts, jquery

Once in a while when I come across excellent screencast tutorials 
I download them for viewing offline. Any ideas on how I can extract this tutorials from this [particular jquery site](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/)?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [FlashGot](http://flashgot.net/getit) addon for firefox.  After the addon is installed, simply load the page, start the video playing, then press ctrl-f7 to download the active media.

Answer (score 0):

Safari for Mac has an Activity monitor that allows you to view the elements on the page that are currently being downloaded and that have finished downloading.  I tested for your web site and the file:

http://a8.video2.blip.tv/1740000452935/NETTUTS-jQueryForAbsoluteBeginners144.flv?bri=3.5&brs=549

... is what is loading for the first tutorial on that page.  VLC media player will play .flv files. Not sure if there are rights issues associated with this but that's how it's done. If you're on a PC I can't help.

**Update** Okay for the PC you can use the Firefox plugin "[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)" to monitor all net activity for the page.

1. After installing firebug, load the
   page and turn the plugin on.
2. Click the "Net" tab and enable it.
3. Click the "Flash" submenu item and it will show you what you want when the sitemakes the request (i.e., when you press play on the flash player)

Comment: That link does the magic. However am on a PC and I use mozilla.Any addons that can help?

Comment: As Joel Harris recommended, use the FlashGot addon and then you can use VLC to play/transcode the videos to a different format if necessary.

Comment: Okay firebug might be overkill if FlashGot works well for you.

Comment: Flashgot has done the trick for me.